# How to Retrieve Firebase User Information

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio

I'm building simple app that has three activities (LoginActivity, CreateAccountActivity and ProfileActivity). A user can login to ProfileActivity through LoginActivity if he has existing account if not he has to go to CreateAccountActivity and create a user account by providing his credentials (FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress, Password and Age) then click the CreateAccount Button. By clicking the CreateAccount button the user will be directed to the ProfileActivity. In the ProfileActivity the user will see all his profile details (FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress, Password and Age). User profile details are obtain through object of java class called UserDetails.

Problem
The problem I'm having is that user profile details will not be shown in the ProfileActivity when user login with an existing account but will only show after creating account. Since the user has already created an account, I want the user to see his profile details (FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress, Password and Age) each time he login to his ProfileActivity through LoginActivity.
NB: To avoid duplication of question, I have searched to know if I can find any similar problem but to no avail so I will be glad if someone can help me with the answer or provide a link that will help me solve my problem.

Here is my ProfileActivity.java

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
// valuable declaration

    private TextView FirstName, LastName, Password, Email, Age;

// FirebaseUser, databaseReference and string valuable declaration

    private FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
    private DatabaseReference reference;
    private String userID;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_activity);

        FirstName = findViewById(R.id.TvFirstNameValue);
        LastName = findViewById(R.id.TvLastNameValue);
        Password = findViewById(R.id.TvPassword);
        Email = findViewById(R.id.TvEmail);
        Age = findViewById(R.id.TvAge);
        
// initializing firebaseUser, databaseReference and string valuable

        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        userID = firebaseUser.getUid();

        reference.child(userID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
// calling the java class that contains user details

                UserDetails userProfile = snapshot.getValue(UserDetails.class);
                if(userProfile != null){
                    String user_FirstName = userProfile.First_Name;
                    String user_LastName = userProfile.Last_Name;
                    String user_Email = userProfile.Email;
                    String user_Password = userProfile.Password;
                    String age = userProfile.Age;
                                       FirstName.setText(user_FirstName);
                    LastName.setText(user_LastName);                   
                                        Password.setText(user_Password);
                    Email.setText(user_Email);
                    Age.setText(age);

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
Toast.make text(ProfileActivity.this, "something happened", Toast.Length_Short).show(); 

            }
        });
    }

}
```

UserDetails java class

```
public class UserDetails {

    public String Email, Password, age, Act_PinNumber,  First_Name, Last_Name;

    public UserDetails(){

    }

    public UserDetails(String Email,String Password,String age,String  First_Name, String  Last_Name){
        this.Email = Email;
        this.Password = Password;
        this.age = age;
        this.First_Name = First_Name;
        this.Last_Name = Last_Name;

    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't have any error but the codes are not working as I expected. I want user details to display each time user login after creating user account.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: I found out that the problem was because I didn't connect to the internet. Thanks @Alex Mamo for trying to help me.